# How do you filter in Python using a function?

Tags: python, function, filter

I am using the filter function for the first time and using a function to remove del_num from a tuple called num_list. However, it's not doing what I want. I am getting back the original num_list values. Appreciate any ideas on how to get this to work.

```
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,8,24,24,54,78]
del_num = 24

def filter_list(num_list, del_num):
    new_num =[]
    for v in num_list:
        if (num_list) == (del_num):
            return FALSE
        else:
            new_num.append(v)
    return new_num

result = filter_list(num_list,del_num)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making minimal changes to the overall structure of your code, but making some changes so it works:

```
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,8,24,24,54,78]
del_num = 24

def filter_list(num_list, del_num):
    new_num = []
    for v in num_list:
        if v != del_num:
            new_num.append(v)
    return new_num

result = filter_list(num_list,del_num)
print(result)
```

The `return False` portion of your code will break out of the function and return `False` if the condition is met, which is not what you want. Additionally, the equality check you were doing was comparing the original list to the number to be deleted. You should have done `if v == del_num`. Given that all the action happens in the `else` block, easiest to turn the equality into an inequality and get rid of the `else` block entirely.

Also note that the boolean False is spelt `False`, not `FALSE` (unlike some other languages).

Comment: Thanks. What does v! do? Assuming one can change the tuple to a list and get this to also work.

Comment: `!=` is the inequality operator - the opposite of `==`.  `v != del_num` is asking whether an individual list item is NOT EQUAL to `del_num`. I'm not sure what you mean about changing the tuple - there aren't any tuples in the code.

Comment: Clarifying my question. If i change the input values to strings, will this function initialize. I tried it and it doesnt work.

Comment: The function should still work, but may not do what you intend: `filter_list('aabcda', 'a')` returns `['b', 'c', 'd']`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using list comprehension

```py
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,8,24,24,54,78]
del_num = 24

def filter_list(num_list,del_num):
    return [num for num in num_list if num != del_num]

filtered_list = filter_list(num_list,del_num)
print(filtered_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what are you looking for:

```
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,8,24,24,54,78]
del_num = 24
```

def filter_list(num_list, del_num):

```
 new_num =[]

for v in num_list:
    if (v) == (del_num):
        pass
    else:
        new_num.append(v)
return new_num
```

result = filter_list(num_list,del_num)

print(result)